# Question about cyclic subgroup of a non-abelian group of order $8$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How is it true that a non-abelian group of order $8$ is guaranteed to have a cyclic subgroup of order $4$? Such a subgroup would be normal since it will have index $2$. Finally, what's a good example of any group of order $8$ that does not admit a cyclic subgroup of order $4$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group of order $8$.

For $G$ to have a cyclic subgroup of order $4$, it suffices to have an element $a ∈ G$ of order $4$, then you can take the subgroup generated by $a$.

- If $G$ has an element $g$ of order $8$, $a = g^2$ has order $4$, so
- if $G$ has no element of order $4$, then every nonidentity element of $G$ has to have order $2$, because their order has to be one of the nontrivial divisors $2, 4, 8$ of the group order $8$. So for each $g, h ∈ G$, you get $g = g^{-1}$, $h = h^{-1}$ and $gh = (gh)^{-1}$, so
  $$gh = (gh)^{-1} = h^{-1}g^{-1} = hg,$$
  so the group must be abelian.

Hence, every nonabelian group of order $8$ has an element of order $4$.

For a abelian group without an element of order $4$, take $(ℤ/2ℤ)^3$ – this is the only one (up to isomorphisms).

Comment: In your answer, in the first line did you mean a "group of order $8$?"

Comment: @Libertron Yes, of course I did.